# Running a job in parallel with N concurrent threads

Tags: c#, unit-testing, task-parallel-library

Sometimes I need a test method to be executed simultaneously by N threads (like what happens in ASP.NET code).

Is there an easy way to do that with `Task Library` ?

```
[TestMethod()]
public void DoSomethingTest()
{
    // Do something which has concurrency issues i.e. database, IO, ...
    DoSomething();
}

// Something like:

[TestMethod()]
public void DoSomethingTest()
{
    int n = 1000; // run 1000 of DoSomething() simultaneously
    Parallel.Invoke(() => DoSomething(), n);
}
```

Comment: running 1000s of them is not realistic. Think `NumberOfCores * F` where F is 0.5 .. 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a Parallel.For :

```
[TestMethod()]
public void DoSomethingTest()
{
    int n = 10; // changed to 10, see comment
    Parallel.For(0, n, i =>  DoSomething());
    // here all threads are completed 
}
```

But note that the TPL will decide the amount of parallelism, much like the ASP.NET Threadpool...

You can add ParallelOptions to set the degeree of parallelism but I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I test some methods parallel with the TPL.

Here is some example code :

```
var parent = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var tasksI = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Constants.TaskCount; i++)
                        DoMethod1Parallel();

                });

                var tasksII = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Constants.TaskCount; i++)
                        DoMethod2Parallel()

                });

                tasksI .Wait();
                tasksII.Wait();
            });

            parent.Wait();
            Assert.AreNotEqual(parent.IsFaulted, "Executing is faulted!");
```

I call Method1 and Method2 more than once and with the TPL parallel. So I can verify the capability of parallel execution!

Regards, patrick

Comment: I need a large number of `N` and cannot setup them manually like what you did.